# How to print byte representation of a string?

Tags: python, string, byte

So I have a string like `"abcd"` and I want to convert it into bytes and print it.

I tried `print(b'abcd')` which prints exactly `b'abcd'` but I want `'\x61\x62\x63\x64'`.

Is there a single function for this purpose or do I have to use unhexlify with join?

**Note**: This is a simplified example of what I'm acutally doing. I need the aforementioned representation for a regex search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single function to do it, so you would need to do the formatting manually:

```
s = 'abcd'
print(r'\x' + r'\x'.join(f'{b:02x}' for b in bytes(s, 'utf8')))
```

Output:

```
\x61\x62\x63\x64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get hex values of a string like this:

```
string = "abcd"

print(".".join(hex(ord(c))[2:] for c in string))
```

Comment: Thank you :) I just assumed with Python being Python that there is a one-function solution.

Comment: There isn't a one-function solution because Python doesn't consider the representation `'\x61\x62\x63\x64'` more useful or basic than `"abcd"`, which in turn is because Python doesn’t have a byte datatype. The elements of the string are either small integers (as in `b'abcd'`) or characters (as in `"abcd"`) and the natural way to present characters is, well, as characters. Hex escapes are reserved for bytes that aren't characters and can't be otherwise represented. If you want to see `a` as `\x61` then there are ways to do it, but the is no reason to privilege `\x61` over `\x0061` or `\X61`.